# Extracting method signatures from C# classes

Tags: c#

Can someone please tell me how I can extract all the method signatures from a C# class? This class as such is not avaiable to my program (that is the project holding the class is not loaded in the Visual Studio).

Comment: you can View the class in Object Explorer or you can right click on class name and select Go to Definition (F12) and VS will show the members from meta-data.

Comment: Is this at design time or runtime?

Comment: I can accept only when I get a satisfactory answer that mostly helps me solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here's [a link to a nice piece of code](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2008/12/reflection-in-c-list-of-class-name.html) to get you started. The concept is [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), by the way.

You should be able to copy and paste that code pretty much as is. Just provide the path to the assembly that you want to examine. If you only want a single, particular class then you fill have to add that filter.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. But I don't have any access to the assembly (dll). I am looking at the class from SVN (repository), and we don't store dll in SVN. However, we have msi's that are created by compiling the projects. Can you please tell me if I can it any other way?

Comment: You could check out the projects (and the files/classes) you need from SVN, perhaps to a separate solution, so that you could examine the code more easily. Btw, if they exist in your SVN repo and are part of your solution and build process then they will exist as .NET assemblies at some point. You could also run the installer on your dev machine and examine the output, e.g. assemblies, in the Program Files folder.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Two things. First, the files/classes are not part of my solution. Second, the classes are part of build process, that is controlled by a separate system outside of SVN, and does not store the assemblies/dll's in SVN. Can I get the method information by looking at the msi database?

Comment: MSI won't know much about the internals of the libraries you're using. It mostly needs to know their names, target destinations and their type. So no, looking at the MSI won't help. Installing the app might be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

So... you have the code and want to know the functions in that class?

Does opening the files which implement the class\ right-click\ Outlining \Toggle All Outlining in VisualStudio solve your problem?